# Editing 'Open With' menu in Windows 11

Tags: windows, windows-11

Ever since I pressed the 7-zip console by mistake, I keep seeing this open with 7-zip console menu in every single file extensions.

I've already removed the 7z app, but the problem continues.
What can I do to remove the menu from all of the 'Open With' menu?

[image: 1]